# Tagging Xubuntu when Ubuntu is meant

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm basically doing limited patrol for [Xubuntu Team](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-team) to keep an eye on questions and have done a couple tag edits relative to the [xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu) tag.  While I am aware [of the prior discussion of tagging flavors and editions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/250/how-to-tag-the-ubuntu-editions-and-derivatives) a problem arises that users seem to be attempting to tag with [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) but accept [xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu) which is offered as auto-completion.  This winds up with non-germane questions classified under the Xfce-based flavor that need to be moved out.

Is there a good way to work around this in terms of user interface adjustment perhaps?

Comment: Well, we can start by editing their tag wiki excerpts to be correct. How high does the recommendation come for you? On a blank question it recommends xubuntu and lubuntu at 5th and 6th place. I'm not sure there is too much we can do about that..

Comment: I'm very wary of the so called "flavor tags". I prefer people to tag their questions that are relevant to xfce as [tag:xfce]. I doubt that as tag flavors is relevant information that doesn't have another tag already, like xfce tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit those mistagged questions. That should be first step. As long term solution, maybe we should reconsider the [current policy](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/250/169736). People tagging with these tags normally do it because they are just trying to tell that they are using a flavor of Ubuntu, not that is in any way relevant to their specific problem.

I would suggest, merging l/xubuntu into lxde and xfce. Seems more sane.

Comment: That's one area where this is still somewhat tricky.  You can have a plain vanilla LXDE/Xfce installation using the pure upstream packages.  Those will differ from Lubuntu and Xubuntu as they will lack the integration work that was done by the flavors and that gives you four different DE software stacks.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat but then... who use that if they can have ready to use packages ;). IMO, flavors versions aren't so relevant for most of the questions I read and are easily applicable to Xfce/LXDE. Maybe is my own biased point of view, but that's what I felt.

Comment: I thought somebody was messing with us but [there was a conversation in #xubuntu-devel about this](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2014/09/08/%23xubuntu-devel.html#t03:17)...

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat I've seen those... trainwrecks.