# Icons for top relvent tags

Tags: feature-request, design

I just noticed that with Stack Overflow's tags many of the tags have nice fancy icons:

[image]

Wondering if we could get some tag bling as well? Certainly some of the browsers/top programs may benefit from this, maybe we could make a short list of some that would benefit. I'm thinking things like Xubuntu and Kubuntu, GIMP, Software Center perhaps.

[image]

Sample incorporation into our tag style

Comment: Tags get logos because the companies sponsored them. Now, that doesn't mean we can't get any mind you. I'm not sure what they consider sponsorship. I like the idea though, and the mockup.

Comment: We did get a Xubuntu guy in here saying he was patrolling for the team: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11946/tagging-xubuntu-when-ubuntu-is-meant also ubuntu-one is one that was followed by Canonical if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes, many teams actually monitor tags here. I know the dev team monitors the [tag:application-development] tag, for example.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good idea.

Since Ask Ubuntu's relationship to the Ubuntu project is far tighter than the relationship between SE/SO and any sponsoring company, it stands to reason that at least the official Ubuntu and Ubuntu-related projects and products merit nifty tag icons.

(Provided, that is, that they already have tags, and that a suitable icon exists.)

This would include [edubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/edubuntu), [juju](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/juju), [kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kubuntu), [kylin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kylin), [launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/launchpad), [lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lubuntu), [maas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/maas), [mythbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mythbuntu), [software-center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-center), [ubuntu-gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-gnome), [ubuntu-studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-studio), [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch), [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity), [xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu) and probably a handful of others.